# Send image with HttpClient to POST WebApi and consume the data

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

My `HttpClient` sends the image with `PostAsync`.
I am not really sure what to do now since this is my first REST Api and I can't really adapt the things I sorted out in other posts yet.
Hopefully you guys can help me out and can give me a direction.

```
public async Task SendImage(string fullFileName, string fileName)
    {            
        var client = new HttpClient();
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://x.x.x.x");

        var content = new StringContent(fullFileName, Encoding.UTF8, "image/jpg");
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync($"/values/file/{fileName}", content);
    }
```

I have several questions about the POST function.
First of all I can successfully access it with `PostMan` and the `fileName` is correct.

How do I read the image data and write it to a file?

```
[HttpPost("file/{fileName}")]
public void Upload(string fileName)
{        
    Debug.Write(fileName);
}
```

EDIT:

I setup my environment and I can now send a post via the internet to my published Web Api.
On my app just nothing happens.
For now I just tried to get something of a message to work on but I dont getting one.

```
[HttpPost("file/{fileName}")]
public HttpResponseMessage Upload(UploadedFile fileName)
{
    Debug.Write(fileName);
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {

    }
    if (fileName == null)
    {

    }

    string destinationPath = Path.Combine(@"C:\", fileName.FileFullName);
    System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(destinationPath, fileName.Data);
    HttpResponseMessage rm = new HttpResponseMessage();
    rm.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK;
    return rm;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going fine until you're trying to retrieve the image data, I'm afraid.

According to your question:

> How do I read the image data and write it to a file?

All you want to do is getting the file's data and its file name and sending it to your service.

I would personally create an `UploadedFile` class on both sides (client and service side), having the file's name and its data, so:

```
public class UploadedFile
{
    public string FileFullName { get; set; }
    public byte[] Data { get; set; }

    public UploadedFile(string filePath)
    {
        FileFullName = Path.GetFileName(Normalize(filePath));
        Data = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
    }

    private string Normalize(string input)
    {
        return new string(input
                .Normalize(System.Text.NormalizationForm.FormD)
                .Replace(" ", string.Empty)
                .ToCharArray()
                .Where(c => CharUnicodeInfo.GetUnicodeCategory(c) != UnicodeCategory.NonSpacingMark)
                .ToArray());
    }
}
```

Then you will need, for example, the NewtonSoft's JsonConvert in order to serialize the object and send it through.

So now you would be able to send your data async:

```
public async Task SendDataAsync(string fullFilePath)
{
    if (!File.Exists(fullFilePath))
        throw new FileNotFoundException();
    var data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new UploadedFile(fullFilePath));
    using (var client = new WebClient())
    {
        client.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.ContentType, "application/json");
        await client.UploadStringTaskAsync(new Uri("http://localhost:64204/api/upload/"), "POST", data);
    }
}
```

Now, **make sure you correctly handle the request** on the server side. If for whatever reason the parameters doesn't match it won't enter into the method (remember having the same model/class - `UploadedFile` on the service as well).

On the service, just change the arguments of your method and perform something "like this":

```
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage Upload(UploadedFile file)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        ...
        
    if (file == null)
        ...
    string destinationPath = Path.Combine(_whateverPath, file.FileFullName);
    File.WriteAllBytes(destinationPath, file.Data);
}
```

Hope it helped you having an idea about what to do and what you're actually doing wrong. I've exposed something similar based in my experience.

**EDIT**: I've actually uploaded an example with both sides working: a simple .NET Core console app which retrieves a file and sends it through `POST` and a basic `WebAPI2` service with a simple controller to retrieve the data. Both ready to go and tested working! Download it [here](https://gofile.io/?c=OhBkVM).

Enjoy.

Comment: I'll give it a shot right now. Thanks for your effort!

Comment: Now I have an FileNotFoundException. Thats interesting.

Comment: @paulvoelker Where are you getting the `FileNotFoundException`? If you're getting it on client side, review you're passing the full file path to the constructor, or try performing a `File.Exists(path)` . Debugging will tell, probably.

Comment: Well, I do check this. I've removed the referenced from `Normalize` and now I am getting a `DirectoryNotFoundException`. Debugging is kind of hart since I only can test it on my physical iPhone.

Comment: @paulvoelker No worries. The `Normalize` method was there to prevent weird chars. You might be giving the relative path instead of the absolute path. Make sure you're actually providing the actual path of the file, I mean: `c:\temp\photo.jpg` instead of `photo.jpg`. This last one would try to read the file from wherever the program is being executed (project\bin\debug) resulting on that `FileNotFoundException`

Comment: It has clearly something to that I am renaming the file...hmm. Well I changed it back and now at least this works. Thanks! I will go on.

Comment: @paulvoelker Keep going! I've updated my solution to check if file doesn't exist in first instance. Good luck and I know it could seem more complex than your original example but it will allow you to upload "anything". If you finally get it and found my solution helpful, I would appreciate you marking it as solution.

Comment: Sure, I will. Thanks! :)

Comment: Hey Gonzo, now I configured my environment to test it from Front- to Backend. When I am sendig one image nothing happens. I am not even getting an exception. I'll edit my code that you can see what I did (not much so far).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185194/discussion-between-gonzo345-and-paulvoelker).

Answer (score 1):

1.Your controller should look like this:

```
//For .net core 2.1
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Index(List<IFormFile> files)
{
    //Do something with the files here. 
    return Ok();
}

//For previous versions

[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Index()
{
    var files = Request.Form.Files;
    //Do something with the files here. 
    return Ok();
}
```

2.To upload a file you can also use Multipart content:

```
        public async Task UploadImageAsync(Stream image, string fileName)
        {
            HttpContent fileStreamContent = new StreamContent(image);
            fileStreamContent.Headers.ContentDisposition = new System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue("form-data") { Name = "file", FileName = fileName };
            fileStreamContent.Headers.ContentType = new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            using (var formData = new MultipartFormDataContent())
            {
                formData.Add(fileStreamContent);
                var response = await client.PostAsync(url, formData);
                return response.IsSuccessStatusCode;
            }
         }
```

3.If you are uploading **large files** you should consider **streaming** the files instead, you can read about it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-2.2)

Comment: Adding the ContentDisposition and ContentType, as you describe, finally helped solve my issue. Thank you!